# Mod Rewrite rules for multiple parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have and URL which is

```
homepage/profile.php?id=15&username=dinesh.kumar
```

now i would like to generate URL something like this...

```
homepage/dinesh.kumar
```

want permanent redirection. Can some one help me please...it may be very simple but my knowledge on this is zero.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: Which http server are you running? This should be as simple as setting a rule in your http server's config.

Comment: It is Apache Server..and would like to write rule in .htaccess

Comment: This is a duplicate btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698828/how-to-make-a-better-url-with-htaccess-and-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using [mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting/)

Your rule will look something like:

```
RewriteRule /homepage/(.*)/(.*)$ /homepage/profile.php?id=$1&username=$2
```

Comment: thank you ... but here id=15 is not constant that will be keep on changing ..it may be id=10 or id=9 and so on..

Comment: @monamona Okay but the url you want to redirect to (dinesh.kumar) does not contain the id!?! You will at least need to redirect to /dinesh.kumar.15 or something

Comment: Thanks...but dont know how to handle this..can i make it something like this...  homepage/15/dinesh.kumar

Comment: @trideceth.. thank you very much...for your help..but the thing is it does not look easy for remembering..i wanted to implement it something like facebook/dinesh.kumar but in my case now there is id in-between..would u be able to suggest...any alternative for this...

Comment: @monamona if the username and id are both essential, then the user will have to specify them. You could have your script check usernames against a database of ids but if each unique username has a unique id you probably don't need to have an id at all!

Comment: thank you very much...i got it now i have decided to have unique username...and it will solve my issue...but as i said..i am very bad in mod-rewrite..i have another question..if you can have look...and guide..me that will be really...great..thank you in advance... here is the link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12233947/mod-rewrite-rule-for-parameters