# mod rewrite rule for parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have below url(s)

```
www.localhost.com/profile.php?username=first.last
```

i would like to permanently redirect above url to using .htaaccess file. (apache server)

```
www.localhost.com/first.last
```

please also consider there are few other urls there but i dont want to touch them..like

```
www.localhost.com/message.php?id=12
www.localhost.com/editprofile.php?editname=first.last
www.localhost.com/uploadphoto.php?username=first.last
```

can anyone please help me.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to handle the Query String with `RewriteCond` and pass the captured match to `RewriteRule`. You must exclude any `.php`scripts of your rewriting rule otherwise it will create some problems with others URLs.

Don't forget to add the [QSA] tag after your `RewriteRule` otherwise it will not add the Query String parameters.

Maybe doing something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

#serve any existing php scripts as usual
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.php) - [L]

#and now handle your specific stuff:
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\./[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(%1)$ /profile.php?username=%1 [QSA]
```

I don't test it but it should be a good beginning. You can read some good stuff [here](http://borkweb.com/story/apache-rewrite-cheatsheet) and inside the docs for [mod_rewrite httpd 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/fr/rewrite/) about how to write and handle specific rewriting use cases.

Comment: @Thierry...thank you for answer...but really my knowledge on mod-rewrite is blank...if you can telle me how exactly i should implement this that would be really good...

Comment: I will give try to this...lets see...thank you very much @ThierryB